# InetAddress.getByName() failing for hostnames without suffix

Tags: java, dns, inetaddress

I added a static DNS entry into my router, binding some IP address to `builds-mac`. I then attempted to look up its IP address using Java:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Testcase
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException
    {
        System.out.println("got: " + InetAddress.getByName("builds-mac"));
    }
}
```

This failed with:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: builds-mac
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1246)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1162)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1048)
```

but when I replaced the hostname with `builds.home.local` (updating the DNS entry accordingly) then the operation succeeded.

Why does `InetAddress.getByName()` require a hostname suffix? Is it possible to make it work for hostnames without a suffix?

(I am running JDK 1.7.0_60 under Windows7, 64-bit)

**UPDATE**: `nslookup builds-mac` always works whereas initially `ping builds-mac` fails (`could not find builds-mac`) but then when I launch the virtual machine in VMWare, `ping` begins to work. Once `ping` begins to work, so does `InetAddress.getByName()`.

1. Why would `ping` fail to find a host when `nslookup` does?
2. Why would launching the VM cause `ping` to begin seeing the host? Remember, `ping` says `could not find builds-mac` as opposed to finding the host but not getting any response because the host is down. The latter is expected, but the former is not.

**UPDATE2**: So, I've discovered three more interesting clues...

1. Whenever `ping` works so does `InetAddress.getByName()`. This is not the case for `nslookup`.
2. By default, routers are not assigned a domain name. In this mode, `nslookup` always works but `ping` does not.
3. If I assign the router a domain name and renew [1] the lease of the computer doing the lookup, then `ping` begins to work.

[1] Rebooting the computer or running `ipconfig /renew` picks up the new domain name, but `ipconfig /flushdns` does not.

So, this brings us back to the original question:

**Why does the Windows Client Resolver (what `ping` uses under the hood) require a domain name suffix?** I mean, shouldn't it work even without one?

Comment: Does it work when you `ping builds-mac` from that Windows 7 machine (without using Java)?

Comment: I suspect `ipconfig /renew` might also have worked, but I (like your maid) don't really **do** Windows.

Comment: I used Google, where I found this beauty `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've added more clues. See update #2 :)